# Is it possible to declare a generic type constraint for value or string types when combined with C# 8.0 nullable reference types?

Tags: generics, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I've written two abstract classes that represent the base class for entities: One where the `Id` property is an **int**, another that allows to specify the type of the `Id` property using a generic type parameter `TId`:

```cs
/// <summary>
///     Represents the base class for all entities.
/// </summary>
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the ID of the entity.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
///     Represents the base class for all entities that have an ID of type <typeparamref name="TId"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TId">
///     The type of the <see cref="Id"/> property.
/// </typeparam>
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class BaseEntity<TId>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the ID of the entity.
    /// </summary>
    public TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

These classes are defined in a core assembly which I use in nearly all projects I work on. Since C# 8.0 came out, I've experimented with enabling [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), which has worked out well so far.

However, in the case of `BaseEntity<TId>`, the compiler gives a warning:

> *Non-nullable property 'Id' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the property as nullable.*

I understand the warning, but I can't seem to fix the issue for my use case. More specifically, I want to allow declaration of types that derive from:

- `System.String`, i.e. `BaseEntity<string>`
- Any value type, e.g. `BaseEntity<System.Guid>` or a custom struct

Since `System.String` isn't a value type, this doesn't seem to be possible: If I constrain `TId` to structs (`BaseEntity<TId> where TId : struct`), I can't declare `BaseEntity<string>` any more.

The only solution (?) I've found so far to disable the warning, is initializing the `Id` property with its default value and using the `!` operator:

```cs
/// <summary>
///     Represents the base class for all entities that have an ID of type <typeparamref name="TId"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TId">
///     The type of the <see cref="Id"/> property.
/// </typeparam>
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class BaseEntity<TId>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the ID of the entity.
    /// </summary>
    public TId Id { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

However, I'd like to make the intent of the code clear: That `TId` can be a value type (e.g. short, long, `System.Guid`, ...), **OR** a `System.String`.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: By the way, you may want to disallow nullable reference for `TId`, you cans use `where TId : notnull` to prohibit `class Entity : BaseEntity<string?>` usages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no such constraint - whether you're using nullable reference types or not.

What you *could* potentially do is use a private constructor to make sure that only types declared within the base type can derive from `BaseEntity`, and then use two specific versions:

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntity<TId>
{
    public TId Id { get; set; }

    private BaseEntity<TId>(Id id) => Id = id;

    public class StructEntity<T> : BaseEntity<T> where T : struct
    {
        public StructEntity() : base(default) {}
    }

    public class StringEntity : BaseEntity<string>
    {
        public StringEntity(string id) : base(id) {}
    }
}
```

That would still let you work with `BaseEntity<T>` in most places, but any time you wanted to *construct* an entity, you'd need to pick between those two.

I've no idea how that will tie in with supporting serialization, although I'd personally steer clear of binary serialization anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and also for your comments on using the `System.Serializable` attribute @Jon Skeet! I'll consider removing them.